# How to use wildcard symbol in SQL query that is assigned as parameter value using SET?

Tags: sql, sql-server, wildcard

What is missing in following query?

It get an error

> The data types varchar and varchar are incompatible in the modulo operator

My code:

```
DECLARE @SQLStatement AS VARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @GroupName VARCHAR(100) = 'abc xyz abc'

CREATE TABLE #a 
(
    col1 INT, 
    col2 VARCHAR(50), 
    col3 VARCHAR(100)
)

SET @SQLStatement = 'INSERT INTO #a
                        SELECT col1, col2, col3
                        FROM Group
                        WHERE GroupName like '+@GroupName+''%''' '

PRINT (@SQLStatement)
EXEC (@SQLStatement)

SELECT * FROM #a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use parameters and `sp_executesql`:

```
SET @SQLStatement = '
                        INSERT INTO #a
                        SELECT col1, col2, col3
                        FROM Group
                        WHERE GroupName like @GroupName + ''%''
                    ';

exec sp_executesql @SQLStatement, N'@GroupName varchar(100)', @GroupName = @GroupName;
```

It seems unlikely that this does anything useful,  Presumably, you intend:

```
WHERE ' ' + GroupName + ' ' LIKE '% ' + @GroupName + ' %'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your @SQLStatement should be as follows.

```
SET @SQLStatement = 'INSERT INTO #a SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM Group WHERE GroupName LIKE '''+@GroupName+'%''';
```

However, you should consider not doing dynamic SQL for this for the entire statement.  You could get away with just the `@GroupName` parameter being constructed.

Also, look into understanding [SQL Injection Attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and you may well rethink this approach entirely.

Comment: Also, I agree with @Gordon - sp_executesql is the better way vs. EXEC() as it is parameterized.